# embedded stylesheet with angular-defined values

Tags: angularjs, pseudo-class

I am repurposing the HTML/CSS for this survey widget.

The CSS is built for a fixed number (5) of options (radio buttons), but I can dynamicize it using `ng-repeat` so that it can hold anywhere from 3 to 9 options, as the data requires.

The CSS needs to be dynamic as well to account for a variable number of options.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="widget-wrapper likert-scale-widget" action="">
        <ul class='likert1'>
            <li ng-repeat="option in item.response.options>
                <input type="radio" name="likert" ng-value="option.value">
                <label>{{option.label}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS makes extensive use of pseudo-classes:

```
div.likert-scale-widget .likert1:before {
    top: 11px;
    left: 9.5%;
    display: block;
    width: 78%;
}
```

You can't put pseudo-classes directly inline, so I can't do this:

```
<div class="likert-scale-widget">
<div class="likert1" style="width:78%">
```

So what I have to do is embed my styles in a  element at the top of the page. Then I can target it with `Angular`:

```
<style>
div.likert-scale-widget .likert1:before {
    top: 11px;
    left: {{ 12 - item.response.options.length*1.1 }}%;
    display: block;
    width: {{ 74 + item.response.options.length }}%;
}
</style>
```

Problem is, this is very non-standard markup. My GUI hates the multiple use of parentheses.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-style`. Looks really hackish, but if your styles are dynamic towards the content, then I guess its justifiable.

Declare a variable to get the entire styles in a key value format.

```
$scope.likerStyle = {
    'top': '11px';
    'left': (12 - item.response.options.length*1.1) + '%'; // '+' automatically stringify this
    'display': 'block';
    'width': (74 + item.response.options.length) +'%';
};
```

Then at your markup, use this:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="widget-wrapper likert-scale-widget" action="">
    <ul class='likert1' ng-style='likerStyle'> 
        <li ng-repeat="option in item.response.options>
            <input type="radio" name="likert" ng-value="option.value">
            <label>{{option.label}}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I incorporate pseudo-classes? That's the sticky bit. eg. ul.likert1:before

Comment: but is the part where you need pseudo class dynamic? i.e, need the values from your controller? if not, you can just define it at your style sheets

Comment: Yes. See last code block in opening post. (how I'm doing it now)